# Two Dishes at once

Tags: oven

I am cooking cheesy potatoes and pineapple stuffing for Christmas dinner.  Both require a 350 degree cooking temperature, one takes an hour, the other an hour and fifteen minutes, can I cook them in the same oven?  I'm using a Samsung oven (not the convection feature.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can cook them together. Compared to others this time of year, you've got it easy. Keep an eye on them, sometimes one dish can block the other from cooking evenly, especially if they are on different shelves. You may need to rotate, so give yourself a little extra time as that will cause the oven to cool down, as will adding your second dish after the first one has started.